# Saving Schema-less Records with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I've been trying to save CSP reports into Mongoose with a Mixed schema and have ran into a snag of sorts.

If I try to save anything using the "schema-less" way, it only saves the default `_v` and `_id` fields

```
ViolationSchema = new Schema({});
Violation = mongoose.model('CSPViolation', ViolationSchema);

... wait for POST ...

new Violation( req.body ).save( callback );
// { _id : <some_id>, _v : <some_hash> }
```

If I set a field in the schema to be `Mixed` and add a `.markModified()` to the field, it will save.

```
ViolationSchema = new Schema({ report : { type : Mixed } });
Violation = mongoose.model('CSPViolation', ViolationSchema);

... wait for POST ...

var v = new Violation( { report : req.body } );
v.markModified('report');
v.save( callback );
// report saved under v.report.<actual_report>
```

I thought about using native MongoDB-style `collection.insert`, however it doesn't look like the model has an insert method (nor the schema for that matter).

I suppose I could also go over each key in the report I'm saving and manually mark it as modified, but I'd like to avoid that just to store a report such as this.

Any ideas how I can blindly save a mixed schema type using Mongoose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this can be done by setting `{ strict : false }` [on the schema.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)  This ensures that Mongoose will save any fields that weren't declared in the original schema.

Normally this isn't something you would enable on 95% of your data, it just fits perfectly with what I'm trying to do currently.

## Example

```
ViolationSchema = new Schema({ type: Mixed }, { strict : false });
Violation = mongoose.model('CSPViolation', ViolationSchema);

... wait for POST ...

new Violation( req.body ).save( callback );
// Saves with full data
```

Comment: So it's been more than an year now. How is your experience with using schema-less Mongoose? Would you still do it the same way?

Comment: @a20 I only used a schema-less model for one specific use-case (capturing CSP violations), which I then plug into a separate app that's basically a glorified JSON reader.  Schema-less is useful for blindly dumping data into the DB, but I wouldn't do it for pieces of data that have a lot of business logic tied to it.